# Implicit declaration of function fmax

Tags: c, c89, ansi-c

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%f\n", fmax(1.2, 3.4));
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile with:

```
gcc a.c -o a && ./a
```

then I get the expected output:

```
3.400000
```

If I try to enable warnings though and target C89, I can't get it to compile:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c89 -pedantic -Wstrict-prototypes a.c -o a
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:5:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fmax’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
a.c:5:5: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]
/tmp/cc8d2iQl.o: In function `main':
a.c:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `fmax'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c89 -pedantic -Wstrict-prototypes a.c -lm -o a
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:5:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fmax’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
a.c:5:5: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]
```

I found out that `fmax()` is only defined by the C99 standard, not C89. So the question is: why do these exact same commands work without issuing any warning on a Mac, but not on a Linux machine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to build with -std=c99 (see the manual page for fmax).. see [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=31422)

From [fmaxf manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fmaxf)

```
fmax(), fmaxf(), fmaxl():
_XOPEN_SOURCE >= 600 || _ISOC99_SOURCE || _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L;
or cc -std=c99
```

It seems **fmax also requires C99**

Comment: I didn't downvote. I see I was badly misled by the [`math.h` Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_mathematical_functions) stating that "in C89, all functions accept only type double for the floating-point arguments", implying that all functions *are* available in C89, just not the `*f` versions. Editing that page now. But still, the second question stands. Why do I not get any warning on a Mac with the same source and the same `gcc` arguments?

Comment: It will be very helpful if down voting people left a comment on the reason for down vote..

Answer (score 1):

From gcc [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins):

> 5.44 Other built-in functions provided by GCC
>
> GCC provides a large number of built-in functions other than the ones
>   mentioned above. Some of these are for internal use in the processing
>   of exceptions or variable-length argument lists and will not be
>   documented here because they may change from time to time; we do not
>   recommend general use of these functions.
>
> The remaining functions are provided for optimization purposes.
>
> GCC includes built-in versions of many of the functions in the
>   standard C library. The versions prefixed with _*builtin* will always
>   be treated as having the same meaning as the C library function even
>   if you specify the -fno-builtin option. (see C Dialect Options) Many
>   of these functions are only optimized in certain cases; if they are
>   not optimized in a particular case, a call to the library function
>   will be emitted.
>
> Outside strict ISO C mode (-ansi, -std=c89 or -std=c99), the functions
>   _exit, alloca, bcmp, bzero, dcgettext, dgettext, dremf, dreml, drem, exp10f, exp10l, exp10, ffsll, ffsl, ffs, fprintf_unlocked,
>   fputs_unlocked, gammaf, gammal, gamma, gettext, index, isascii, j0f,
>   j0l, j0, j1f, j1l, j1, jnf, jnl, jn, mempcpy, pow10f, pow10l, pow10,
>   printf_unlocked, rindex, scalbf, scalbl, scalb, signbit, signbitf,
>   signbitl, significandf, significandl, significand, sincosf, sincosl,
>   sincos, stpcpy, strdup, strfmon, toascii, y0f, y0l, y0, y1f, y1l, y1,
>   ynf, ynl and yn may be handled as built-in functions. All these
>   functions have corresponding versions prefixed with _*builtin*, which
>   may be used even in strict C89 mode.
>
> The ISO C99 functions _Exit, acoshf, acoshl, acosh, asinhf, asinhl,
>   asinh, atanhf, atanhl, atanh, cabsf, cabsl, cabs, cacosf, cacoshf,
>   cacoshl, cacosh, cacosl, cacos, cargf, cargl, carg, casinf, casinhf,
>   casinhl, casinh, casinl, casin, catanf, catanhf, catanhl, catanh,
>   catanl, catan, cbrtf, cbrtl, cbrt, ccosf, ccoshf, ccoshl, ccosh,
>   ccosl, ccos, cexpf, cexpl, cexp, cimagf, cimagl, cimag, conjf, conjl,
>   conj, copysignf, copysignl, copysign, cpowf, cpowl, cpow, cprojf,
>   cprojl, cproj, crealf, creall, creal, csinf, csinhf, csinhl, csinh,
>   csinl, csin, csqrtf, csqrtl, csqrt, ctanf, ctanhf, ctanhl, ctanh,
>   ctanl, ctan, erfcf, erfcl, erfc, erff, erfl, erf, exp2f, exp2l, exp2,
>   expm1f, expm1l, expm1, fdimf, fdiml, fdim, fmaf, fmal, **fmaxf**, fmaxl,
>   **fmax**, fma, fminf, fminl, fmin, hypotf, hypotl, hypot, ilogbf, ilogbl,
>   ilogb, imaxabs, isblank, iswblank, lgammaf, lgammal, lgamma, llabs,
>   llrintf, llrintl, llrint, llroundf, llroundl, llround, log1pf, log1pl,
>   log1p, log2f, log2l, log2, logbf, logbl, logb, lrintf, lrintl, lrint,
>   lroundf, lroundl, lround, nearbyintf, nearbyintl, nearbyint,
>   nextafterf, nextafterl, nextafter, nexttowardf, nexttowardl,
>   nexttoward, remainderf, remainderl, remainder, remquof, remquol,
>   remquo, rintf, rintl, rint, roundf, roundl, round, scalblnf, scalblnl,
>   scalbln, scalbnf, scalbnl, scalbn, snprintf, tgammaf, tgammal, tgamma,
>   truncf, truncl, trunc, vfscanf, vscanf, vsnprintf and vsscanf are
>   handled as built-in functions except in strict ISO C90 mode (-ansi or
>   -std=c89).

Comment: The second question stands then. Why does `gcc` with the exact same source and exact same parameters not issue any warning on a Mac?

Comment: locate and open you included *math.h*; it should point you to *bin/mathcalls.h*. Inside this, find fmaxf definition and check if it is inside a *#ifdef __USE_ISOC99*

Comment: My Mac's `/usr/include/math.h` doesn't include `bin/mathcalls.h`, but instead it includes a `architecture/i386/math.h`, which doesn't contain any reference to `__USE_ISOC99`. Even so, shouldn't these warnings be generated by `gcc` itself, regardless of what might be available on the system?

Comment: nope it's all if- or ifn- defined or macroed in header files. would you try to find fmax or fmax in your includes and post it in the question?

Comment: All `fmax*()` functions are defined in the architecture `math.h`. But if `gcc` doesn't warn me about using a non-standard function, then what is the purpose of `-std`? What else can I do to be warned about this?

Comment: the purpose of -std is to support some dialect, that is, generally, disabling (or enabling like with -std=gnu99) gnu gcc own extensions and language syntax features (ie oneline comments: // ). It appears to be a bug in the released gcc version for darwin you installed, and you should report it. I think (though not sure of) that gcc is picking up the \_\_builtin\_ function (despite the -ansi)

Answer (score 0):

It's defined by C99 but not C89.

Search "C99" in
[man for fmaxf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fmaxf)